# Default size for empty

Tags: scripting

Is it possible to set the default size of the Empty Object? The problem is since I switched my blender scale to metric, the Empty's default size is kinda large for most times I need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly after you add an Empty press F6 to get the *Add Empty* Operator parameters.

[image]

The *Radius* parameter will set the visual size of the current Empty and all new Empties that you add afterwards during that session.

Unfortunately there isn't a configuration option to set the default radius permanently.

Comment: possibly a script could be told to load on each new .blend file to add an empty and set the radius and remove it (all behind the scenes) -- but simply setting the Radius once is almost effortless too..

Answer (score 2):

When adding an empty from the add object menu, change the radius to the setting you desire. The inverse of the scene unit settings scale_length will give you a result of 1m

This can also be edited on the empties data panel.

The following changes all empties to 1 based on the scale_length.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

scene = context.scene

scale_length = scene.unit_settings.scale_length
empties = [o for o in scene.objects if o.data is None]

for empty in empties:
    # 2.79 :
    empty.empty_draw_size = 1 / scale_length
    # 2.8+ :
    # empty.empty_display_size = 1 / scale_length
```

or calling the operator

```
bpy.ops.object.empty_add('INVOKE_DEFAULT', radius=1 / scale_length)
```

using invoke default keep that value for the next time the operator is run.

Comment: sorry if this sounds just dumb, but can you tell  me where to find that bit of script?

Comment: To run the script, copy, paste into a new text block,  right-click  "run script".

Answer (score 1):

For 2.90+ Blender versions there is now an option to set default empty size for new collection instances.

This won't affect plain empties added from the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Add > Empty* menu, but will set default size for new collection instances added from <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Add > Collection* list.

You can find it under *Edit > Preferences > Editing > New Objects > Instance Empty Size*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For 2.8x replace `empty_draw_size` by `empty_display_size` in batFINGER's code

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

scene = context.scene

scale_length = scene.unit_settings.scale_length
empties = [o for o in scene.objects if o.data is None]

for empty in empties:
    empty.empty_display_size= 1 / scale_length
```